# Best way to iterate over multiindex dataframe and store data in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe [symbol,ohlcv] of stock data (shown below).  I want to iterate over each stock symbol and when I have a match (criteria satisfied), I want to take all the data for that symbol and store it in a new data frame.  So I will have a new dataframe that will be a subset of the original.

What is the best way to do this?

```
symbol  A                                                   AAL 
ohlcv       open    high    low     close   adj     volume  open    high    low     close   ... 
Date                                                                                    
2018-08-31  67.14   67.55   67.05   67.54   67.54   1582400 40.25   40.55   40.18   40.48   ... 
2018-09-04  67.34   67.56   66.85   67.27   67.27   1728000 40.32   41.34   40.32   40.77   ... 
2018-09-05  67.28   67.40   66.76   66.96   66.96   1859600 40.81   41.37   38.88   39.67   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `groupby` and store them in a `dict`

```
d =  {x:y for x,y in df.groupby(level=0,axis=1)}
```

then

```
d['A'] # will out put A
```